# Set proper bits on n-bit number with given decimal value

Tags: c, embedded

Suppose I have the number 0b000 and I need to set the correct bits, so that they will be equal for ex. 5. (0b101).
How do I do that, using bitwise operations algorithm?

Okay, more details then. I'm developing morse code decoder, and to describe a input, I'm using 8 bits: **000 00000**, where first three bits are t**he number of dot/dashes given**, and the rest of bits are reserved for the input, where dot is 0, and dash is 1.
For example, the letter A (.-) would be: **010 01000**.

The question is, how can I modify the first three bits so that they will show how many dot/dashes were given during the input?

Comment: I suggest you start by reading about [bitwise operations in general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).

Comment: Question is not clear. What do you mean by equal? Give another example.

Comment: `0b101` is decimal `5`, not `3`!

Comment: If you always have 0 and always want to set to other number, just use x | other_number. But I have the feeling that is not what you need.

Comment: Also, standard C does not support binary notation.

Comment: By assigning your decimal value to your variable, you automatically set the proper binary bits.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I've added more details to my question, sorry for vagueness.

Comment: You're not going to be able to encode all morse characters with only 5 bits, e.g. punctuation characters typically require 6 (e.g. `?` = `..--..`) and the symbol for "mistake" is 8 dots.

Comment: As @PaulR points out, you may not be able to fit everything in an 8-bit variable.  Bitfields can help with what you want, but it's just as easy in this case to shift your count and OR it into place.  I agree with SomeProgrammerDude that you may want to read up on bitwise operations in general.

Comment: @JoshSanford The C language does not allow to declare 8 bit long bit-fields. Never use C bit-fields, it is a completely broken language feature.

Comment: @Lundin The following compiles just fine under c89:  `struct { uint8_t count : 3; uint8_t bits : 5; } my_struct;`  The result of `sizeof(my_struct)` is 1 as expected.  When working with embedded systems, as the OP seems to be doing, bitfields are reasonable to use.  And if he isn't communicating with hardware, why try to pack two pieces of data into a single variable?

Comment: Null question - you can't pack three bits of number of dots/dashes AND the pattern of dots/dashes into 8 bits likes this.

Comment: @barny Although the question has all kinds of problems, the OP is trying to pack 3 + 5 bits into an 8-bit value.  Why do you say that can't be done?

Comment: @JoshSanford: There is no guarantee for the layout, nor the size of the `struct` to be 1 byte. It is well possible to be padded to the next word (or larger) boundary. Especially for embedd these are vital issues. There is a good reason MCU headers don't use them, but `uintN_t` and bitops instead.

Comment: @JoshSanford Your compiler is bad or misconfigured. Apart from stdint.h obviously not being present in C89, you get the following error when compiling with `gcc -std=c89 -pedantic-errors` "error: type of bit-field 'count' is a GCC extension".

Comment: @JoshSanford OP stated he is encoding morse, and that he is hoping to encode the morse dot-dash pattern into five bits. As PaulR pointed out, there are morse symbols longer than five dots/dashes. If the question were "how do I pack two values with 3 and five bits into 8" that would be, err, a different question.

Answer (score 1):

You switch bits on using `|`. Let's stick with your non-standard notation for binary literals (note that C++14 onwards supports it):

`0b000 | 0b100` is `0b100`.

`0b100 | 0b001` is `0b101`.

Note that you can *toggle* bits using `^` (work through some examples as an exercise).

Finally, you can switch *off* bits using '&~`.

Answer (score -2):

Solved, if you want to set the first 3 bits, then shift 5 bits to the left (where value is the number you want to set on 3 first bits):

```
value = value << 5;
```

And then OR it with the rest of bits:

```
morseBits = morseBits | value;
```

Comment: This is complete nonsense. Shifting 5 bits to the left will only set the 5 LSB to zero, while moving the data you had there 5 bits away. So this code _sets bits 5 to 9_ and not _0 to 2_ which was what the question was about.

Comment: Now if you actually want to set the 3 lowest bits you would do `something = (something & 0xF8) | (value & 0x07)`. I see that you've edited the question so that it asks something else. Please don't do that when there are answers present.

Comment: The "first 3 bits" are bit 2..0, not bit 7..5 .